# Robots.txt redirect loop when use Cloudflare flexible ssl

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, ssl, cloudflare

my magento site https://pimaapparel.com/ is using cloudflare flexible ssl

after

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
```

site stopped redirect loop

after

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://pimaapparel.com/$1 [L]
```

link redirect properly

but now robots.txt is still in redirect loop, everything else works fine. please help

Comment: any other text files are fine, only robots.txt

Answer (score 4):

Can't believe it's that simple.

just make a pagerule, and disable any acceleration on robots.txt

that is it...

Thanks for whoever read my post and tried to think a solution.

Comment: What I actually did is to turn off: "Apps" and set Custom cache to: "Basic caching". Then purged the cache.

Answer (score 0):

For me, Deactivating and Re-enabling WP Fastest Cache solved the issue.